# Can I do a request from inside a WebAPI Controller (or BlazorComponent) using the current NTML context?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, blazor-server-side, .net-5

So currently I am inside of a controller, and I want to call another controller with HttpClient.  But when I do, I get a 401:

```
async Task MakePdf()
{
    var client = HttpFactory.CreateClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(myUrl); // this gets a 401
}
```

I am already authenticated via Windows Authentication, but the request is apparently not sent with the same authorization.  Is there a way to give that client the same credentials as the context inside the controller it is called from?  This is all going to the same app.

This is using Kerberos:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  }
}
```

To clarify, I am logged in just fine, but if I send the request from inside a Controller or RazorComponent I will get a 401.

Comment: Do you use Kerberos? Do you put them on two different servers? From your code, we can not find the problem.

Comment: Yes I do use kerberos, I clarified above